# .NET Maui - Reset Navigation Stack when clicking on the same Tab that is currently displayed

Tags: mvvm, navigation, maui, .net-maui.shell

I want to implement very specific thing for TabBar in my maui shell app. User can now technically go in infinite loop of going in to details page on that one tab.

RootTabPage-> DetailsPage -> DetailsPage -> DetailsPage.... I want to make it possible to go back to the root with one click, so..  RootTabPage -> DetailsPage -> DetailsPage -> DetailsPage -> ClickOnTheSameTab -> RootTabPage.

I've found this code on stackoverflow: [.NET Maui - Reset Navigation on TabBar Item Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73449661/net-maui-reset-navigation-on-tabbar-item-click)

But it will remove stack when going to DIFFERENT tab, which is not what I want and it is UX issue.
I also tried binding CurrentItem in TabBar but it doesn't trigger when going to the same tab i'm on.

So I want to implement the described behavior that is: If I'm on the same tab that I'm clicking on, remove whole stack on this tab. Back button must behave normally that is removing just one page from stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, clicking on active tab does not trigger tab changed event.

- I've added an [open proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15301) describing the desired feature. You are the second person recently to want a way to do this. Unknown whether this will ever be implemented. Perhaps someone will suggest a work-around, either here, or on that maui issue/proposal.
- For now, consider adding a button on every Detail Page, that does
  `Navigation.PopToRootAsync();`

Comment: Thanks, I commented on that. I will wait a bit before closing this question.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and I came up with a workaround (also available in github issue created by ToolmakerSteve).

Keep in mind that this code below is Android only but if you need other platforms the implementation should be similar.

1. In Platforms -> Android -> Resources add MyShellRenderer.cs

```
using Android.Content.Res;
using Google.Android.Material.BottomNavigation;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.Android;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.Compatibility;

namespace YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.Platforms.Android
{
    public class MyShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {
        public MyShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
        protected override IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(ShellItem shellItem)
        {
            return new MyShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker();
        }
    }
    public class MyShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker : IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public void ResetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView)
        {
        }

        public void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
        {
            //example of how to change how TabBar is looking using native properties
            bottomView.LabelVisibilityMode = LabelVisibilityMode.LabelVisibilityUnlabeled;
            bottomView.BackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Colors.Gray.ToAndroid());
            bottomView.ItemActiveIndicatorColor = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Colors.White.ToAndroid());
            bottomView.ItemIconTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Colors.White.ToAndroid());
            bottomView.SetPadding(100, 0, 100, 0);
            
            //clear NavigationStack when the same TabBar page is selected again
            bottomView.ItemReselected += ItemReselected ;
        }

        private void ItemReselected (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             var navigation = Shell.Current.Navigation;
             var pages = navigation.NavigationStack;
             for (var i = pages.Count - 1; i >= 1; i--)
             {
                 navigation.RemovePage(pages[i]);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

2. In MauiProgram.cs add at the end of builder extensions

```
 .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
                {
#if ANDROID
                    handlers.AddHandler(typeof(Shell), typeof(Platforms.Android.MyShellRenderer));
#endif
                });
```